# Read and close a group of files

Tags: python

I need to write a piece of code that will open read and close files in a directory. The problem I'm having is that the files aren't necessarily named in a ordered convention. Is there a function or loop that will step through the files in the directory in whatever order or name they are?

Comment: `os.walk` sounds like what you want

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of options:

- `glob.glob`
- `os.listdir`
- `os.walk`

`glob.glob` returns a list of filenames that match a pattern

```
glob.glob("my_music/*.mp3")
```

`os.listdir` returns a list of filenames in the specified directory:

```
os.listdir('/usr/local/bin')
```

`os.walk` is a more complicated beast which handles subdirectories - see https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk for detailed examples.

All of these return lists of filenames that you can then sort according to your requirements and then iterate across.